# Video-react in videoJS not loading after src is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video, video.js, video-reactjs

I am using Video-react (https://video-react.js.org/components/player/) and on the page, it says I can use `this.refs.player.load()` once I have updated its source. But I do not think that method is supported any more as It will not work at all plus I could not find it in the source code downloaded with npm.

Is there another way to do this or has anyone found a solution? This is my partial code:

```
                var videoRow = document.createElement("div");
            videoRow.className = 'col-md-4';
            videoRow.setAttribute("id", "videoRows");
            //create the myPlayer div which will contain the Player. 
            var myPlayerDiv = document.createElement("div");
            myPlayerDiv.setAttribute("id", "myPlayer");
            //create my player with the information from the attributes.
            var videoPlayer = document.createElementNS('', 'Player');
            videoPlayer.setAttribute("src", data.val().videoURL);
            videoPlayer.setAttribute("ref","player");
            myPlayerDiv.appendChild(videoPlayer);
            videoRow.appendChild(myPlayerDiv);
            document.getElementById('videoList').appendChild(videoRow);
             this.refs.player.load();
```

This has not worked. I tried renaming the ref but still nothing. The div shows up but not the player.

Edit: Just found this in the Player.js component but can't figure out how to implement it: [Player.js component source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hMu6.png)

Answer (score 1):

The reason `this.refs` is not exists is because your code is simply touch the DOM directly rather than use React lifecycle. Please modify code in the following manner

```
import React from 'react';
import { Player } from 'video-react';

class DisplayVideo extends React.Component {
    render () {
      const { data } = this.props
      return (
        <div className="col-md-4" id="videoRows">
          <div id="myPlayer">
            <Player src={data.val().videoURL} ref={(el) => this.player = el} />
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }

    componentDidMount () {
      this.player.load()
    }
}
```